# "Residente permanente" - any max period of use limitation?

Tags: resident-permit, mexico

As far as I know, the "residente temporal" status in Mexico has a limitation for how long you can use it - 4 years; after that you have to abandon it or apply for the "residente permanente" status.
I wonder if "residente permanente" has similar limitations? I can't find any information about this.

Comment: If the status has limitations, they are likely to concern how long you can stay outside the country without losing status. It won't have limitations on how long you can *retain* the status; after all, that's precisely what *permanent* means.

Answer (score 2):

The [Surviving Yucatan](https://www.gob.mx/tramites/ficha/cambio-de-residente-temporal-a-residente-permanente/INM823) has an article with a good overview:

> **Advantages and Disadvantages of Residente Permanente vs. Residente Temporal Immigration Permits for Mexico**
>
> - Residente Permanente offers the ease of a single, one-time application/registration.
> - There is only one payment needed for Residente Permanente vs. 4 years of Temporary Resident payments.
> - Residente Temporal card holders must change to Residente Permanente after four years of Temporary Residency anyway (or change to 6 month Visitor permits).
> - If you have a Residente Permanente card, your Notary may approve you for the Home-owners exemption from paying the 25% gains tax on a future sale of your Mexican home – a potential savings of $10′s – $100′s thousands of dollars.
> - If you are outside Mexico for part of the year, Residente Permanente keeps you from having to return to Mexico to deal with an expiring Residente Temporal card.
> - Residente Permanente allows you to work in Mexico, and to get an RFC from Hacienda.
> - Residente Permanente is a good stepping stone to becoming a Naturalized Citizen. Why?  If you have property under a Fidei Comiso, then getting Citizenship allows you to terminate the Fidei Comiso , saving you $ thousands in annual payments to the bank.

Note that, while this article was posted in 2013, and the expat author chooses anonymity, the contents are current, e.g., with the most recent [updates to Mexican immigration issues and rules](https://yucalandia.com/answers-to-common-questions/new-rules-and-procedures-for-immigration-visiting-and-staying-in-mexico/#General) published in June 2017.

Comment: Entonces, I don't see any disadvantages, only advantages of permanente over temporal